# Convolution $f* \delta_h$ and integral of a function, $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, convolution

We consider $h>0$ and $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. We have $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt$.

How to express $F_h : x \rightarrow \int_x^{x+h} f(t)dt $ in the form $ f* \delta_h$ for a $\delta_h \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ ?

I really need help for this. Someone could help me ?

Comment: *Hint:* $$ F_h(x)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(t)\chi_{[x,x+h]}(t) dt $$ Now rewrite the characteristic function $\chi$ in a suitable way to find $\delta_h$.